# Enupal PDF plugin: Passing Variable to Template

Tags: pdf, plugin-enupalpdf

I'm using the Enupal PDF plugin and am trying to pass a variable ID into my template that generates the PDF... I'm assuming the following documents how to pass the variable through to the template - (see image):

[image]

But what I'm not told is how I should print this out in the pdf template. Outputting {{ foo }} doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This probably won't help much, but {{ foo }} should work, i. e. it works in my usage of the plugin. So whatever the problem is, it's probably not your syntax as described above.

Comment: Hi Dan, were you able to fix this issue? I'm unable to recreate this issue

Comment: I believe this is due to an environment issue. Seems to work on local and production but not staging.